# Put already running exe on top of windows

Tags: c#, winforms, exe

I am working on a Winform application. On button click I need to launch a new 3rd party exe. For this I am using the following code:

```
private void btnUserMgmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsAlreadyRunning())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process
        {
            StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = strAppPath + "ReveaLINXUserMgmt/ReveaLINXUserMgmt.exe",
                Arguments = "192.168.0.121\\TESTDBSERVER",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            }
        };
        proc.Start();
    }
} 


private bool IsAlreadyRunning()
{
    var processExists = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().Any(p => p.ProcessName.Contains("ReveaLINXUserMgmt"));
    return processExists;
}
```

Now it is launching fine and running on the top of my main application window.

I need when some one again click `btnUserMgmt` button. If ReveaLINXUserMgmt.exe is already running and in minimized state, it will come on top of window.

If user closes the main application, child exe will also to be closed

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: There's a big difference between making a single instance application (where you control the code), and launching a single instance of a third-party application.  Your duplicate was invalid.

Comment: It is third party exe. so won't be able to edit its class libraries

Comment: If you use CreateNoWindow = true and the app "runs on top" then something went drastically wrong.  There's in general limited wisdom in manipulating windows owned by another process.  Set the button's Enabled property to *false* when you start the process.  Use the Process.Exited event to set it back to *true*.  Problem solved, the user knows how to use the taskbar button.

Comment: @HansPassant Good idea for avoiding writting code for checking the exe instance is running or not. I am going to use it